# Pandas vs list (time and memory)

Tags: python-3.x

I have large file ~3GB which I used to store into list and but it create memory issue, But need input on following point

1. Pandas is slow compare to list ( I think everyone will agree)
2. I have tried to capture memory usage but did not success
3. Is it possible in pandas dataframe to use filebased rather than keeping all data into memory.

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/emv python
    import time
    import pandas as pd
    import linecache
    import os
    import tracemalloc
    import logging
    import linecache

    def main():
        data = "large_file"
        st = time.time()
        ndata = []
        tracemalloc.start()
        # with open(data, "r") as fp:
        #     ndata = fp.readlines()
        # l_data = ndata[15000:30000]
        # l_data = ndata[30000:45000]
        # print ("list_time", time.time()-st)
        # st = time.time()
        ndata = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter = "\n", header=None)
        l_data = ndata[15000:30000]
        l_data = ndata[30000:45000]
        print ("dataframe", time.time()-st)
        snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
        tracemalloc.stop()
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        display_top(snapshot, logger)

    def display_top(snapshot, logger, key_type='lineno', limit=20):
            """
            display top
            :param key_type: how we determine memory trace
            :param limit: limit
            :param logger:
            :return:
            """


        snapshot = snapshot.filter_traces((
            tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"),
            tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<unknown>"),
        ))
        top_stats = snapshot.statistics(key_type)

        logger.info("Top %s lines" % limit)
        for index, stat in enumerate(top_stats[:limit], 1):
            frame = stat.traceback[0]
            # replace "/path/to/module/file.py" with "module/file.py"
            filename = os.sep.join(frame.filename.split(os.sep)[-2:])
            logger.info("#%s: %s:%s: %.1f KiB"
                  % (index, filename, frame.lineno, stat.size / 1024))
            line = linecache.getline(frame.filename, frame.lineno).strip()
            if line:
                logger.info('    %s' % line)

        other = top_stats[limit:]
        if other:
            size = sum(stat.size for stat in other)
            logger.info("%s other: %.1f KiB" % (len(other), size / 1024))
        total = sum(stat.size for stat in top_stats)
        logger.info("Total allocated size: %.1f KiB" % (total / 1024))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
   ```